# counting word frequency in a string across columns in R

Tags: r, string, select, dplyr, count

I am trying to get a count of how many times each word appears total for every index of a column for my whole data set.  The data can be found here:https://www.kaggle.com/tovarischsukhov/southparklines

My code is as follows:

```
SP = read.csv("All-seasons.csv")
SP$Season = as.numeric(SP$Season)
SP$Episode = as.numeric(SP$Episode)

Cartman = SP %>% group_by(Character) %>% 
  arrange(Season, Episode) %>%
  filter(Character =="Cartman")

Cartman_text_tbl <- as_tibble(data.frame(uniqueID = 1:length(Cartman$Season),Cartman[1:length(Cartman$Season),]))

Cartman_text_tbl_words <- Cartman_text_tbl %>% select(uniqueID,Cartman$Line) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, Cartman$Line) %>% filter(str_detect(word,"^[a-z']+$")) %>%
  group_by(uniqueID) %>% count(word)
```

When I run the last line of code I get this error:

```
Error in `select()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `Yeah, go home you little dildo.\n`, `I know what it means!\n`, `I'm not telling you.\n`, `He-yeah, that's what Kyle's little brother is all right!  Ow! \n`, `That's 'cause I was having these... bogus nightmares.\n`, etc. don't exist.
```

I did a project for a class a couple of years ago where the professor provided some similar code, I am trying to format this code off what was previously provided for me.  If there is a better way to get a count that would be awesome to know about as well, otherwise a way to fix the error would be great.  Additionally, each line ends with a "\n" I was wondering if its possible to remove those from every column? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the error message. You sre selecting a column Cartman$Line, but this means you are passing the values of that column, not the actual column name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I believe this may help you. The output gives you the count of each word said by Cartman for each episode and season. Of course for other characters you can use the same code and change the filter and object the output is assigned to. Also if you need to remove stop words you can add `anti_join(stop_words, by = "word") %>%` after the `unnest_tokens()` function. It is also set as `sort = TRUE`, so it will sort the words in descending order based on frequency, so you can change this and sort as needed.

**Code:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

df <- read_csv("All-seasons.csv")

cartman <- df %>%
  filter(Character == "Cartman") %>%
  group_by(Season, Episode) %>%
  unnest_tokens(output = word, input = Line) %>%
  count(word, sort = TRUE)
```

**Output Example:**

```
> head(cartman)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Season, Episode [6]
  Season Episode word      n
   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <int>
1      7      11 you      73
2     11       8 i        73
3      5       4 you      66
4     16       7 you      63
5     14       8 i        61
6     11       2 i        60
```